# Python append value in 2D Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, 2d

I have the following dictionary and I would like to append one more array to 'CorrectionsAll'. I tried Append option but I couldn't get what I needed. Could someone please help me with the logic.

```
Dict1 = {'ShpmtID': 123, 'PickupDate': '2016/01/01 00:00:00', 'EstimatedDeliveryDate': '2016/01/10 00:00:00', 'OrigSic': 'LJB', 'DestSic': 'XCF', 'CorrectionHistory': [{'key': 405013, 'CorrectionsAll': [{'CorrChngDesc': 'Commodity Line Changed'}]}]}
```

Wanted to add "Discount Line changed" as follows:

```
{'ShpmtID': 123, 'PickupDate': '2016/01/01 00:00:00', 'EstimatedDeliveryDate': '2016/01/10 00:00:00', 'OrigSic': 'LJB', 'DestSic': 'XCF', 'CorrectionHistory': [{'key': 405013, 'CorrectionsAll': [{'CorrChngDesc': 'Commodity Line Changed'}, {'CorrChngDesc': 'Discount Line Changed'}]}]}
```

> **Copy Comment**: tried these two options:

Option-1:

```
Dict1["CorrectionHistory"]["CorrectionsAll"].append({'CorrChngDesc': 'Discount Line Changed'})
```

Option-2:

```
Dict1["CorrectionsAll"].append({'CorrChngDesc': 'Discount Line Changed'})
```

Comment: work your way through the structure to get the proper value and append the new dict to it. Do you have some code you can show that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just access the list you want and then append to that

```
Dict1['CorrectionHistory'][0]['CorrectionsAll'].append({'CorrChngDesc': 'Discount Line Changed'})
```

Outputs:

> {'OrigSic': 'LJB', 'PickupDate': '2016/01/01 00:00:00', 'DestSic': 'XCF', 'ShpmtID': 123, 'CorrectionHistory': [{'key': 405013, 'CorrectionsAll': [{'CorrChngDesc': 'Commodity Line Changed'}, {'CorrChngDesc': 'Discount Line Changed'}]}], 'EstimatedDeliveryDate': '2016/01/10 00:00:00'}

Comment: It will give `keyError`

Comment: Hi Reedinationer,

I did try this option but I am getting the following error:

KeyError: 'CorrectionsAll'

Comment: @mad_ Yeah I made a mistake, should have tested it locally, but was feeling lazy cause the OP didn't even post an attempt

Comment: @roganjosh you are correct. I needed to index the dict then the list, then the other dict

Comment: @ChristianDean Thanks! I ran it locally and figured that out just as you posted it

Comment: No problem! @Reedinationer

Comment: Thanks everyone and Thanks Reedinationer!

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried these two options: Option-1: Dict1["CorrectionHistory"]["CorrectionsAll"].append({'CorrChngDesc': 'Discount Line Changed'})

Option-1 won't work because `"CorrectionAll"` is not an element of `"CorrectionHistory"`, but of a list. That list, IS an element of it though.

```
Dict1["CorrectionHistory"][0]["CorrectionsAll"] # Use [0] to go inside this list !
```

> Option-2: Dict1["CorrectionsAll"].append({'CorrChngDesc': 'Discount Line Changed'})

Option-2 won't work either, because `Dict1["CorrectionAll"]` doesn't exist. It's again, not a direct element of it, but I think you can understand why now.

Comment: Thank you @Fukiyel for your explanation. I understand it much better now.